# How two merge two queries into one result set without duplicates?

Tags: sql, h2

I have a table with three columns id, name, training_run_id, named_entity_id.
I would like to make result set with two name columns but with different type_id

```
SELECT r1.id, r1.f1, r2.id, r2.f1 FROM
    (
        SELECT id, f1  from RESULT where TRAINING_RUN_ID IN (1,2) AND NAMED_ENTITY_ID = 13
        GROUP BY ID
    ) as r1
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, f1 from RESULT where TRAINING_RUN_ID IN (3,4) AND NAMED_ENTITY_ID = 13
        GROUP BY ID
    ) as r2
```

Result of the query is:

```
id  f1   training_run_id id  f1    training_run_id
27  0.3    2             41  0.5    3
27  0.3    2             55  0.66   4
13  0.2    1             41  0.5    3
13  0.2    1             55  0.66   4
```

I am wondering how to get this one:

```
id  f1  training_run_id id  f1   training_run_id
13  0.2   1             41  0.5    3
27  0.3   2             55  0.66   4
```

Comment: Does h2 support row_number() ?

Comment: @Serg yes, h2 support that function

Comment: What relationship has id 13 with id 41. Why for instance you don't combine 13 with 55 on the same row? Is there a rule you apply here?

Comment: @trincot I missed to add column training_run_id, updated now I think more clear

Comment: What if your 1st subquery returns 2 results, and the 2nd subquery returns 3 results, what would be the expected result then?  The logic behind the question is not clear.

Comment: @sstan all subqueries returns the same quantity

Comment: Ok, then the next question is, why are `13` and `41` paired together in the 1st row and `27` and `55` in the 2nd row.  Why not `(13, 55)` and `(27, 41)`? What is the logic?  Or maybe you don't care, and just want them paired up randomly, as long as the 4 results are never repeated, 2 per row.

Comment: @sstan it doesn't matter I just would like to see in the result set two columns f1 together without duplications. Ids just for clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of assumptions (based on OP's comments):

- Your 2 subqueries always have matching row counts
- How the rows are matched is unimportant

If the above is true, I think you can simply have each subquery return `rownum` so that you can join on that to avoid a cartesian plan:

```
SELECT r1.id, r1.f1, r2.id, r2.f1 FROM
(
    SELECT rownum as rn, id, f1  from RESULT where TRAINING_RUN_ID IN (1,2) AND NAMED_ENTITY_ID = 13
    GROUP BY ID
) as r1
JOIN
(
    SELECT rownum as rn, id, f1 from RESULT where TRAINING_RUN_ID IN (3,4) AND NAMED_ENTITY_ID = 13
    GROUP BY ID
) as r2
ON r1.rn = r2.rn
```

**EDIT**

Actually, not too sure if the above will work correctly, because as specified in the documentation about the [rownum function](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#rownum), it seems like `rownum` gets computed ***before*** the `group by`.

> To get the row number after ordering and grouping, use a subquery.

If that's the case, I think this is the correct query:

```
SELECT r1.id, r1.f1, r2.id, r2.f1 FROM
(
  select rownum() as rn, id, f1
  from (
    SELECT id, f1  from RESULT where TRAINING_RUN_ID IN (1,2) AND NAMED_ENTITY_ID = 13
    GROUP BY ID
  ) t
) as r1
JOIN
(
  select rownum() as rn, id, f1
  from (
    SELECT id, f1 from RESULT where TRAINING_RUN_ID IN (3,4) AND NAMED_ENTITY_ID = 13
    GROUP BY ID
  ) t
) as r2
ON r1.rn = r2.rn
```

Comment: thank you, it works if remove "GROUP BY ID" from the query!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Qualify Statement. I have just used your code for creating the table above. The you can then partition the data by R1.ID which will separate all of the data into partitions on the user ID, you then order by R2 ID descending ad then you qualify the statement by Row_number() = 1 which will take the lowest R2.ID number within the partition and delete the rest of the results

```
   SELECT r1.id, r1.f1, r2.id, r2.f1 FROM
        (
            SELECT id, f1  from RESULT where TRAINING_RUN_ID IN (1,2) AND NAMED_ENTITY_ID = 13
            GROUP BY ID
        ) as r1
        JOIN
        (
            SELECT id, f1 from RESULT where TRAINING_RUN_ID IN (3,4) AND NAMED_ENTITY_ID = 13
            GROUP BY ID
        ) as r2
    QUALIFY (ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY R1.ID ORDER BY R2.ID ASC)) = 1
```

Comment: I didn't think H2 supported windows functions like `row_number() over (partition by ...)`. Was the feature added recently?  Or did you use a different database?

Comment: My bad sstan I noticed eugenn saying H2 supports row_number() above